# Are there extreme low temperature (-30°C) issues when shooting with a mirrorless and camera and zoom lenses?

Tags: zoom, mirrorless, cold, extreme-sports, durability

What reliability and durability issues can I expect from mirrorless cameras (like a Sony A7) and zoom lenses at extremely low temperatures like -30°C (-22°F)?

Lower battery life is clear, but what about the camera and lens?

- Will it photograph reliably or will it stop shooting?
- Are there any risks to durability of the zooming mechanism, shutter, or other components?

Does anybody have experience shooting in such low temperatures?

Please distinguish theory from experience in answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operating camera in Arctic winter](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/96403/operating-camera-in-arctic-winter)

Comment: Also related: [What should I consider when using DSLRs in cold weather?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/5664/15871) and [Can lenses be damaged by rapid temperature and/or humidity changes?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/102978/15871) and [I accidentally refrigerated my lens for a month. Should I be worried?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/53870/15871)

Comment: Thank you @michaelC, those almost solve the question. I asked about even lower temperatures and it would be great to have all the answers consolidated, but it seems nobody here has more knowledge anyway.

I would summarize the knowledge there:
– no damage observed while using, but avoid condensation when returning to warm humid room (isolate camera and allow it to warm up slowly)
– display/EVF can slow down so much it can become useless
– focussing/zoom slows-down

If it is according community standards, it is OK to close this question for that reasons or aggregated answer can be done.