# How can I prevent condensation on a camera lens?

Tags: lens, equipment-protection, environmental-dangers, humidity, condensation

Is there anything out there to prevent condensation on camera lens? Taking Pictures on a golf course in Florida, camera was out in golf cart at least an hour and a half, when I took pix a lot were hazy.

Comment: See http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/14873/15871

Comment: Does your golf cart have an airco?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I hasten the safe transition from air conditioning to hot/humid outdoors?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14873/how-can-i-hasten-the-safe-transition-from-air-conditioning-to-hot-humid-outdoors)

Answer (score 2):

Condensation happens when the glass surface is significantly cooler than the temperature of the air hitting it.

Keeping the lens warm will prevent it misting up.

The comment you got asking you if your golf cart has air conditioning is relevant.  If you're keeping the camera cool in between shots then this could contribute to the issue.

The greater the temperature difference between the glass surface and the air, and the greater the relative humidity of the air, the more likely you are going to get condensation.  In other words, the relative humidity of the air dictates at what temperature differential moisture will condense on surfaces.

Your specific question was about how to prevent the condensation from forming, but if you are experiencing unavoidable condensation and you are worried about the negative effects this has on your equipment, [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14873/how-can-i-hasten-the-safe-transition-from-air-conditioning-to-hot-humid-outdoors) may be of use.